# validateFunctionArguments:3379: failed assertion `Fragment Function , The pixel format (MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Unorm) of the texture

Tags: ios, objective-c

**validateFunctionArguments:3379: failed assertion `Fragment Function(ca_uber_fragment_lp0_cp1_fo0): The pixel format (MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Unorm) of the texture (name:) bound at index 0 is incompatible with the data type (MTLDataTypeHalf) of the texture parameter (img_tex_0A [[texture(0)]]). MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Unorm is compatible with the data type(s) (
    float
).'**

When I run my project on iPhone 8, I got this crash error, someone adviced me to set "edit scheme - Options -  Metal API Validation" disabled, and It really can  solve it, But I do not know why ? so I'm looking forward to you give me some suggestions, Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Unorm? Usually MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm or MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm are used with Metal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set colorPixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm for your MTLView and MTLRenderPipelineState

Answer (score 0):

In the metal function, you have one of two options - try changing the texture type from float to half or from half to float.

```
texture2d<float, access::read> myTexture [[texture(0)]]

texture2d<half, access::read> myTexture [[texture(0)]]
```